# UIButton - stretchable background image in one direction only?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, custom-controls

I have a UIButton object where I use a stretchable image for its background, so I can always have flexible button sizes.

The thing is I'd like to have a fixed height OF THE IMAGE (say 32px), but want to have a taller touchable area (Apple UI Guidelines say always at least 44px tall).

If I have a stretchable image in x, it unfortunately stretches in y as well.  I'd like to tell the image not to stretch in y.  Is this possible?

[EDIT]  Yes, it is.  Answering my own question:

Comment: Answer your own question as an answer, not as an edit to the question. You can even accept it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just to help others, I can answer my own question:

```
@interface StretchableXButton : UIButton
{
    CGFloat imageHeight;
}
@property CGFloat imageHeight;  // we need this later when we override an instance method

+ (id)buttonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

and now the implementation:

```
@implementation StretchableXButton
@synthesize imageHeight; 

+ (id)buttonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    StretchableXButton *button = [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ButtonBGNormal.png" ];
    UIImage *highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBGHighlighted.png" ];

    button.frame = frame;
    button.imageHeight = normalImage.size.height;  // we need him later in the method below

    // make the images stretchable
    normalImage = [normalImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:normalImage.size.width/2 topCapHeight:normalImage.size.height/2];
    highlightedImage = [highlightedImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:normalImage.size.width/2 topCapHeight:normalImage.size.height/2];

    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // SET OTHER BUTTON PROPERTIES HERE (textLabel, fonts, etc.)

    [button setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    return  button;
}

// THIS IS THE TRICK.  We make the height of the background rect match the image.
-(CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect bgRect = bounds;
    bgRect.origin.y = (bounds.size.height - imageHeight)/2.0f;
    bgRect.size.height = imageHeight;

    return bgRect;
}


@end
```